# Differencing two AR(1) processes

Tags: autocorrelation, autoregressive

I am hoping that someone can help me.

Taking the AR(1) process $y_t = \alpha y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$, I am trying to compute the covariance of the differencing process $w_t = y_t - y_{t-1}$.

I think there are two ways to look at this problem - one is to compute an innovation sequence which gets messy very quickly. The other is to compute the covariance generating function which I think (this could be wrong) is $2\gamma_1 - \gamma_2 - \gamma_0$. Could someone let me know their view on:

a) The covariance function? 
b) How the variance can be recovered from the covariance function?

Thanking you all in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi: Using the lag operator, results in:

$y_{t} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \rho^{i} \epsilon_{t-i}$

$y_{t-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \rho^{i-1} \epsilon_{t-i-1}$

Then, to find the variance of the difference ( I assume that you meant variance and not covariance ? ) , $var(y_t - y_{t-1})$ , all the $\epsilon_{i}$ are independent, so you subtract the second from the first and compute it.

I have to leave and it looks like it will be complicated but you can use 
var(x-y) =  var(x) + var(y) - 2 cov(x,y). The var terms are straightforward and the covariance terms are only those where the subscript of $\epsilon_i$ are the same. Hopefully, someone can finish this but that's the idea.

ADDENDUM SINCE YOUR NEW COMMENT: if you want to calculate the covariance at the different lags, this is how you would do that.

The covariance at lag one is the covariance between observations that are 1 unit apart. So,  you want

$covariance(y_t - y_{t-1}, y_{t-1} - y_{t-2})$.

So, you need to first

A) calculate the difference the two things I calculated. Call it $z_t$.

B)  Lag the thing in A and call it $z_{t-1}$.

C) calculate $cov(z_t, z_{t-1})$.

This will be the covariance at lag 1.

Does that make sense. I don't have time right now to do that but can it get you started ?

Note: Maybe there's a more straightforward way to do this so, if anyone
reading this, knows of one, please chime in. It looks like this is becoming more complicated than it possibly should be ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi - thank you for your reply. It actually is the covariance function I am looking to compute. I then want to recover the variance from it (i.e. $\gamma_0$). I honestly have gotten so lost I have tried many different things. I think I must be missing something somewhere

Comment: Hi: That's okay. You can calculate the covariance at the different lags. I didn't realize that that was you wanted. Let me edit the answer and see if I can clarify.